# Spouse Visa UK, does the spouse need to intend to reside in the UK for a spousal visa application?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, uk-visa

It is unclear to me whether someone applying for a UK spouse visa needs to intend to reside in the UK for the duration of the visa. My spouse, in order to fulfil a contract for funding their education is required to spend several years working in their home country, and is unable to move to the UK with me on a more permanent basis. We have been looking at visa types, as we would still like to be able to visit with each other over this time, and a visa that would allow multiple entry into the UK over several years would be ideal.

A spouse visa is one we were considering, but it is unclear to me how our situation would be viewed, and if acceptable for a spouse visa application.

(We were recently had a rejection for a visitor visa, and are curious about alternative options).

Comment: The Immigration Rules https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-8-family-members talk about ‘a view to settlement’. After a recent refusal for a visitor visa, the application for which presumably included demonstrating ties to home country, it might be difficult to argue that the intention is to settle. I’d suggest you seek the advice of an Immigration lawyer

Comment: It doesn't sound like she qualifies for the Spouse visa. It could be tricky, but entirely possible, to get a visitor's visa. Just have to provide very solid evidence of the situation you describe. Note, once you go for a Spouse visa, there's not really any going back. If that fails, she will effectively never get a visitor's visa to 'visit' you. @Traveller's advice is the best.

Comment: I agree with the others. I think that you should take another stab at the visitor visa, this time with the advice of an immigration solicitor. Given the circumstances, you ought to be able to get one. And the cost of a visitor visa is significantly less than a spouse visa.